# ReportViewer com Subrelatorio - Erro ao processar subrelatorio

Tags: c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == true)
    {

        Sipom.DataSets.RelatorioTableAdapters.TodasTabelasTableAdapter Tabela = new
        Sipom.DataSets.RelatorioTableAdapters.TodasTabelasTableAdapter();
        Sipom.DataSets.Relatorio.TodasTabelasDataTable data = Tabela.GetDataTodos();

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SetSubDataSource);

    } 

    public void SetSubDataSource(object remetente, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {

        Sipom.DataSets.RelatorioTableAdapters.TodasTabelasTableAdapter Tabela = new Sipom.DataSets.RelatorioTableAdapters.TodasTabelasTableAdapter();
        Sipom.DataSets.Relatorio.TodasTabelasDataTable data = Tabela.GetDataTodos();
        ReportDataSource RDS1 = new ReportDataSource("DSRespostas", (System.Data.DataTable)data);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS1); }
```

Com este código estou tentando processar o sub-relatório porém aparece o erro na seguinte linha: `ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS1);`

ERRO:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: O objeto de controle visualizador está no modo somente leitura

Alguém me pode ajudar? Não estou conseguindo resolver este problema. O que eu quero é carregar o relatório principal com o sub-relatório utilizando o `tableadpater`.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Vasconcelos! Enquanto você aguarda alguém que saiba responder à sua pergunta, faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender o porquê do Chun ter editado a sua pergunta... Valendo uma medalha! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa,

No seu método método `SetSubDataSource` tente adicionar a DataSource usando o "e" que você recebeu como parâmetro, por exemplo, ao invés de fazer:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS1);
```

Tente alterar para:

```
e.DataSources.Add(RDS1);
```

Se funcionar, marque a resposta como válida. Valeu!

Comment: Olá Andre, obrigado pela ajuda,

Comment: Desta forma gerou a pagina sem erros, porém o Subrelatório não é chamado, em seus conhecimentos esta chamada esta correta? Neste caso as tabelas do banco não esta sendo carregada com as informações no objeto RDS1 ele esta como nulo, mas quando chega na linha e.DataSources.Add(RDS1); consigo visualizar meus campos da tabela, mas as informações não são carregadas, mas há informações no banco de dados.

Comment: Veja este link tem mais detalhes do que estou utilizando: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/d4f37e8f-0099-40e5-b220-2e77b0062393/reportviewer-subrelatorios?forum=vscsharppt&prof=required

Comment: Você pode continuar carregando sua datasource como estava fazendo, só indiquei o modo correto de adicioná-la ao subreport, no caso só mude aquela linha do ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS1);

Mesmo assim não funciona?

Comment: Depois de uma série de tentativas consegui reconhecer o subrelatório, mas estou tendo alguns problemas com meu Dataset, ele esta quadriplicando as informações do banco de dados. Saberia me dizer o porque? Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Neste link tem mais detalhes sobre a minha postagem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/653949cb-8200-4129-9da4-1ba06dc60f8a/porque-o-dataset-com-tableadapter-esta-quadruplicando-as-informaes?forum=vscsharppt

Comment: As informações estão se repetindo, por causa dos seus Inner Joins. Provavelmente as suas tabelas OpcoesRespostas, Perguntas e Resultadoes são tabelas que possuem vários registros para cada registro da tabela Pesquisa, ou seja 1- N ou N- N...

O que você está querendo listar com esse SELECT?

Comment: Estou tentado trazer as tabelas Pesquisas, Peguntas, OpçoesRespostas, Resultadoes. 

Pesquisas: TituloPesquisa, Populacao, Amostra, Municipio

Perguntas: DescricaoPergunta

OpcoesRespostas: DescricaoOpRes

Resultadoes: OpcaoRespostaId



obs: Neste caso possuímos varias pesquisas em que cada pesquisa possui varias perguntas e cada pergunta possui algumas opções de respostas. Preciso trazer as informações desta forma, mas que não duplique as informações. Será que devo fazer um select para cada tabela ? Obrigado pela imensa ajuda.

Comment: Sim Vanderson, como você possui esse tipo de relacionamento entre as tabelas, se você fizer em um SELECT apenas, vai duplicar as informações das tabelas de nível mais "alto". Eu recomento você fazer um SELECT para as Pesquisas. Aí dentro de cada resultado deste SELECT, você deverá fazer um outro para pegar as Perguntas, passando na cláusula WHERE o Id da respectiva pesquisa. Aí para cada pergunta você faz um SELECT das opções de resposta, passando na cláusula WHERE o Id da respectiva pergunta...e assim por diante.

Comment: OBS: Tome cuidado com popular muitos dados na tela ou relatório, não esqueça que por ter esse nível hierárquico muitas consultas serão feitas, então, o quanto enxuto for sua consulta, melhor será a performance.